# Core-input validation on value commited

Tags: polymer

I'm making a form-like control with lots of inputs, and for that I'm using my own polymer element with a core-input in it. I'm having trouble validating it.

I don't want to set autovalidation for it since almost all of the inputs are required, and i don't like the idea of having a bunch of inputs lined in red and showing errors on page load. What I have (and thought would work) is the following code:

```
<polymer-element name="custom-core-input"
                 attributes="columnId inputError validation inputRequired">
<template>
    <section>
        <paper-input-decorator id="decorator" error="{{inputError}}">
            <input id="custominput"
                   is="core-input"
                   validate="{{validation}}"
                   on-change="{{inputCommited}}"
                   required?="{{inputRequired}}">
        </paper-input-decorator>
    </section>
</template>
<script>
    Polymer({
        inputRequired: false,
        inputCommited: function () {
            this.$.decorator.isInvalid = !this.$.custominput.validity.valid;
        }
    });
</script>
</polymer-element>
```

I threw some alerts on the inputCommited function before, and it looks like the input value is always valid, doesn't matter if it's blank or filled with anything that shouldn't match validate.

As a note, the validation string I'm using is "^(\d*|\d+,\d{1,2})$", I'm asuming this works on Polymer. In any case when required is true it doesn't take blank as an invalid input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `validation` property is a regular expression use `<input pattern="{{ validation }}"...>` and it should work (see [input validation at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms/Data_form_validation)):

```
<input id="custominput"
       is="core-input"
       pattern="{{ validation }}"
       on-change="{{ inputCommitted }}"
       required?="{{ inputRequired }}">
```

The `change` event for a text input is only triggered [if the value is changed and the input loses focus](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/change). There needs to be another mechanism that triggers validation at an appropriate time to make sure every input is validated once, for example, when the form is submitted.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering. I've changed validation with pattern and now it works with a simple reg.expression like this one: ^[0-9]*$     but not with this other one: ^(\d*|\d+,\d{1,2})$ Any thoughts on why could that be?

Comment: In which way is the latter regex not working for you? Both regex seem to work for fine for me. Can you give an example?

Comment: Well, using the first one, I change the input's text and works fine, meaning nothing happens when the text is correct and the decorator shows with an error when it is not correct, as it should. Trying the same thing with the second regex just doesn't react when I put something "wrong" in te input

Comment: The error message is shown for me for inputs like `1,234`, `abc`, `1,`, empty string etc. I tried: `<custom-core-input inputError="Error" validation="^(\d*|\d+,\d{1,2})$" inputRequired></custom-core-input>`. At the very least it should show an error when there is no input (after it changed once).

Comment: Well yes, the empty field error works no matter what. My problem is only with the regex, It just doesnt work. Myabe I'm doing something wrong that I'm not seeing, but as I said the simple regex does work, so it makes no sense to me that the other one doesn't

Comment: I think I've found the problem. The regex was created from some db column values, gettind the allowed number of decimals. Apparently, the one number I was trying it with had no decimals allowed in it, so the regex would be ^(\d*|\d+,\d{1,0})$ which makes no sense.Thanks anyway for the  pattern thing and worrying about this.